# Laravel delete is just not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I tried bunch of methods to delete images but laravel just ignores the deleting part for some reason. I tried to see if it gets the link with `dd($filename)` and it get the link right. I tried `php` `unlink` too but I'm having issue to pass the `path` right with it

```
Storage::delete('storage/images/'.$filename);
```

This is what I try and laravel acts like it de

Comment: Can you post your 'config/filesystems.php' contents for the local disk? Also See https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#the-local-driver
Edit: The reason I am asking is it looks like you are trying to reference the storage directory, but it is already implicitly referenced by using the Storage:: facade, so you should only have to provide the 'images/'. filename

Comment: What's the full path to images directory?

Comment: Ooops sry everybody, I was busy with deploying the website. just saw all these thanks for helping. I will try to provide all the information needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the raw PHP way to do that.

```
unlink('storage/images/'.$filename);
```

`unlink` is working well, and there is no setup required to accomplish it.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a path issue or file permission issue:

```
 $exists = Storage::exists('storage/images/'.$filename);

 if($exists){
    Storage::delete('storage/images/'.$filename);
    //file should be deleted here.... if not check permissions in storage path
    //webserver sys user should have +r+w on storage path 
 }else{
    echo "file not found in ".storage_path('storage/images/').$filename;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more information. Check if you are doing

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
```

before

```
Storage::delete('storage/images/'.$filename);
```

Maybe you have some errors or another debug info?

Comment: Well it is all that is to the function. I get the post id than fine the image that is realted and I find it perfectly well, and when I try to delete it vie laravel, even try to use php unlink. that doesn't work. `Storage::delete('storage/images/'.$filename);` is there too

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to use storage :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
```

then find the file by this code:

```
$file = Storage::exists('storage/images/'.$filename);
```

then delete file if exist:

```
if ($file) {Storage::delete('storage/images/'.$filename)}
else {
 return "File Not exist";
}
```

**N:B make sure that the file that you want to delete have proper permission**

Answer (score 0):

Firstly find the data on particular id
For example

```
$post = \App\Post::find($id);
unlink(public_path().'/uploads/post/'.$post->image);
$post->delete();
```